# How to fetch connect ids from stripe to laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-8

**First Problem:**

I want to dynamically fetch connect id from my stripe account to my laravel controller. How can I do this ?
At present I am setting them manually in controller inside "stripe_account" like this below:

```
['stripe_account' => 'acct_1Mllo..............']
```

**Second Problem:**

In payments section of stripe, the customer field is blank. How to get the customer name ?

[image: payments]

**My controller code:**

```
Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));


$customer = Stripe\Charge::create(
            [
                "amount" => 100 * 100,
                "currency" => "AUD",
                "source" => $request->stripeToken,
                "description" => "This is test payment",
            ],
            ['stripe_account' => 'acct_1Mllo..............']
        );
```

Comment: i'm not entirely certain what you mean by "dynamically fetching your connect id from your stripe account to my laravel controller". In most cases, you should already know what connect account id you want to pass in and have those ids stored in your database/application. If you want to retrieve the full list of connected accounts : https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/list. If you want to retrieve a single connected account,  you need to know the account id : https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve

Comment: you should pass a Customer's id into https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-customer. You can create a customer with https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

1. To dynamically fetch connect ids from your Stripe account to your Laravel controller, you can use the Stripe API to retrieve the list of connected accounts and their respective IDs. You can use the following code to achieve this:

```php
    Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    
    $connectedAccounts = Stripe\Account::all();
    
    foreach($connectedAccounts->data as $account) {
         $connectId = $account->id;
         // Do something with the connect ID, such as saving it to a database.
    }
```

This will retrieve all the connected accounts associated with your Stripe account, and allow you to loop through them to access the connect IDs.

2. To get the customer name associated with a payment, you can retrieve the customer object from the payment object returned by the Stripe API. You can modify your controller code like this:

```php
    Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    
    $payment = Stripe\Charge::create(
                [
                    "amount" => 100 * 100,
                    "currency" => "AUD",
                    "source" => $request->stripeToken,
                    "description" => "This is test payment",
                ],
                ['stripe_account' => 'acct_1Mllo..............']
            );
    
    $customer = Stripe\Customer::retrieve($payment->customer);
    
    $customerName = $customer->name;
```

This will retrieve the customer object associated with the payment, and allow you to access the name attribute.